# Riak, How to delete an index that is already in use?

Tags: python, riak, riak-search

I am willing to delete an index that is already in use on a bucket, using python library:

```
client.delete_search_index(index_name)
```

But i get this error:

```
Can't delete index with associate buckets [{<<"my_bucket_type">>,<<"my_bucket">>}]'
```

I get it, I need to remove the binding between my bucket and my index first. So I try first to disable `search_index` property on the bucket:

```
bucket.set_property('search_index', '')
# or
bucket.set_property('search_index', None)
# or
bucket.set_property('search_index', 'null')
# or
bucket.set_properties('{search_index:null}')
```

Without a success, each time the HTTP error is casted as "`Error setting bucket properties.`" by the library.

I still can assign another riak-search index, but I don't want to stress the riak cluster indexing stuff I won't use.

Is there a way to remove the `search_index` from bucket configuration using the python library ?

Comment: Have you tried removing the search_index property from `<<"my_bucket_type">>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the bucket properties so that

`{"search_index": "_dont_index_"}`

I guess translated to Python it would be

`bucket.set_property('search_index', '_dont_index_')`

After the index has been disassociated from all the buckets it was associated with, you can delete it without a problem.

I strongly recommend you to study the [Riak documentation](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/), it is really good and can save you lots of questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hey, that's indeed in the doc, damnit. Passed over it at least a dozen of time today. This option is cryptic, but it is documented.